# Advanced Custom Fields Plugin - Conflict with Custom Post Type Default Editor

Tags: custom-post-types

Advanced custom fields(2.1.4) plugin disables the wordpress default editor for custom post types. How can I fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields (3.1.5) and attaching it to a custom post type.  I was startled when adjusting some values with my advanced fields that the editor for my custom post type disappeared.

I solved the problem very simply:  On the Edit Field Group page, go to the bottom of the Options section and make sure 'Editor' is enabled in the 'show on page' options.